# Error on SQL connection - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlconnection

I'm having some trouble on connection to my SQL server on my C# application.
I have a code that can either insert or update a table of my database.
If I update the table, everything go rigth, but if I insert it, I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
int ID;
conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = SERVER\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = SQLFiat; User ID = sa; Password = secret");
conn.Open();            

if (cbCarros.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    ID = cbCarros.SelectedIndex + 1;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Carros SET ID_Carro=@ID_Carro,Nome=@Nome,Modelo=@Modelo,Combustivel=@Combustivel,Cambio=@Cambio,Portas=@Portas WHERE ID_Carro=@ID_Carro", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Carro", ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", tbNome.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modelo", tbModelo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Combustivel", cbCombustivel.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cambio", cbCambio.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Portas", Int32.Parse(tbPortas.Text));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Rel_Carro_Apertadeira SET ID_Carro=@ID_Carro,ID_Aper=@ID_Aper WHERE ID_Carro=@ID_Carro", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Carro", ID);
    int ID_Aper = cbApertadeiras.SelectedIndex + 1;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Aper", ID_Aper);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
}
else
{
    ID = retornaMaiorID() + 1;               
    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Carros (ID_Carro,Nome,Modelo,Combustivel,Cambio,Portas) Values (@ID_Carro,@Nome,@Modelo,@Combustivel,@Cambio,@Portas)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Carro", ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", tbNome.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modelo", tbModelo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Combustivel", cbCombustivel.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cambio", cbCambio.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Portas", Int32.Parse(tbPortas.Text));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Rel_Carro_Apertadeira (ID_Carro,ID_Aper) Values (@ID_Carro,@ID_Aper)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Carro", ID);
    int ID_Aper = cbApertadeiras.SelectedIndex + 1;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Aper", ID_Aper);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll executenonquery requires an open and
>   available connection. the connection's current state is closed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for using parameterized queries.

Comment: Aside from the issue at hand you need to look at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ I would recommend using stored procedures instead of pass through sql which is better for a number of reasons including the problems with AddWithValue.

Comment: As advice, do not post credentials anywhere in Internet for obvious security reasons

Comment: You're not assigning the open connection to the command before executing the query.

Comment: @user2366842: Then why does the Update work?

Comment: @user2366842 its passed in the SqlCommand ctor

Comment: @AlexK. - Ah.  Right....looks like I was asleep at the wheel this time.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem, on my function retornaMaiorID() I was closing the connection.
Sorry bother you.

Thanks

Comment: A good lesson in programming, sharing connections can lead to trouble so be careful.

Comment: The pooling feature of the connection class takes care of this for you, don't share connections, use them and get rid of them, behind the scenes will take care of connection management for you.